# Wordpress local dev environment image

Tags: wordpress, docker, vagrant

I would like to set an image for wordpress local environment.
We have developers that are working with Mac, Windows and Linux and I wish that it will be easy to set a working environment.

It is important that they can use an IDE outside the VM for development, and GIT.

What is the best way to achive that?  Docker or Vagrant?

I tried doing so according to this tutorial but there are some stuff wrong with it and it does not working.
https://resources.distilnetworks.com/all-blog-posts/wordpress-development-with-vagrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Varying Vagrant Vagrants](https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/), which is great for WordPress development for a pretty long time, recently I've switched to [Laravel's Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead), which is also great and works fine with WordPress too.

Both are pre-made environments that are easy to install, pre-configured and ready to use. Never had any issues with them.

Comment: Thanks, Can I make Laravel automatically clone a git project, and import SQL dumps to mySQL?

Comment: You can, with some custom shell scripting. Read Homestead's docs.

Comment: For docker, you can create image with all dependencies, push it in docker hub and share it with all devs. You can then use some shell scripting to improve your workflow. Something similar can be found here:
https://github.com/ankitpokhrel/wp-dev

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPTunnel for this purpose.

It creates local WordPress installations inside Docker containers. The source files are mounted from a local directory, so any IDE and Git can access it:

https://github.com/dsdenes/wptunnel

E.g. if you create a local installation with:

`$ wptunnel create mysite`

then you can access the source files at `~/wptunnel/projects/mysite`
So if you want to use a version control tool like Git, then you can do:

`$ git init ~/wptunnel/projects/mysite`

and edit the files with your favorite IDE:

`$ code ~/wptunnel/projects/mysite`

disclamier: I'm the author of the library